# Open wordpress post in a different page

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, blogs, posts

I have two separate pages showing a list of different categories linking to the full post in wordpress. These both currently open on single.php in my theme but The categories need to be styled differently on each page.

I have created the template page but do not know how to open posts on another page other than single.php

to simplify: how do I open posts on another version of single.php

the code I have that opens the full posts are:

```
<?php // PAGE LINK/TITLE          
if (is_page()) {
  $cat=get_cat_ID($post->post_title); //use page title to get a category ID
  $posts = get_posts ("category_name=case-study&posts_per_page=10");
  if ($posts) {
    foreach ($posts as $post):
      setup_postdata($post); 

?>
<div class="serve-inner-split"> 
                <div id="case-split">
                        <div id="case-left" class=" serve-left">
                            <div id="case-study-content">
                                <h1 class="case-study-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                                <p><?php //PULLS IN EXCERPT
                                    $my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
                                    if ( '' != $my_excerpt ) {
                                        // Some string manipulation performed
                                    }
                                    echo $my_excerpt; // Outputs the processed value to the page

                                    ?>
                                </p>
                                <a href="#" class="header-quote">READ CASE STUDY</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="case-right" class="serve-grey">
   <?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // PULLS IN IMAGE check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    the_post_thumbnail();
} 
?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

</div>



<?php endforeach;
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello :) I would achieve this by creating custom post type for each case you need to display the single post differently. You may refer to WP Codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types on this case. Eventually it will allow you to create as much single post templates as you want.

Comment: Or he could just add category fields and style index.php differently ;)

Comment: Custom post type is just my favorite "out of the box" solution, also handy to use for users not familiar that much with WP admin panel :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd create extra category fields. In `functions.php` add

```
add_action ( 'edit_category_form_fields', 'mytheme_extra_category_fields');
add_action ( 'category_add_form_fields', 'mytheme_extra_add_category_fields');

if ( ! function_exists( 'mytheme_extra_category_fields' ) ){
    function mytheme_extra_category_fields( $tag ) {
        $t_id = $tag->term_id;
        $cat_meta = get_option( "category_$t_id");
        ?>
        <tr class="form-field">
            <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="extra1"><?php esc_attr_e('Blog Layout', 'mytheme'); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <select name="Cat_meta[blog_layout]">
                    <?php
                    echo '<option value="layout1" '.selected( $cat_meta['blog_layout'], 'layout1', false).'>'.esc_html__('Layout 1', 'mytheme').'</option> ';
                    echo '<option value="layout2" '.selected( $cat_meta['blog_layout'], 'layout2', false).'>'.esc_html__('Layout 2', 'mytheme').'</option> ';
                    ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <?php
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'mytheme_extra_add_category_fields' ) ){
    function mytheme_extra_add_category_fields( $tag ) {
        $t_id = (is_object($tag))?$tag->term_id:'';
        $cat_meta = get_option( "category_$t_id");
        ?>

        <div class="form-field">
            <label for="extra1"><?php esc_attr_e('Blog Layout', 'mytheme'); ?></label></th>
            <select name="Cat_meta[blog_layout]">
                <?php
                echo '<option value="layout1" '.selected( $cat_meta['blog_layout'], 'layout1', false).'>'.esc_html__('Layout 1', 'mytheme').'</option> ';
                echo '<option value="layout2" '.selected( $cat_meta['blog_layout'], 'layout2', false).'>'.esc_html__('Layout 2', 'mytheme').'</option> ';
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>

        <?php
    }
}
add_action ( 'edited_category', 'mytheme_save_extra_category_fileds');
add_action ( 'created_category', 'mytheme_save_extra_category_fileds');

if ( ! function_exists( 'mytheme_save_extra_category_fileds' ) ){
    function mytheme_save_extra_category_fileds( $term_id ) {
        if ( isset( $_POST['Cat_meta'] ) ) {
            $t_id = $term_id;
            $cat_meta = get_option( "category_$t_id");
            $cat_keys = array_keys($_POST['Cat_meta']);
            foreach ($cat_keys as $key){
                if(isset($_POST['Cat_meta'][$key])){
                    $cat_meta[$key] = $_POST['Cat_meta'][$key];
                }
            }
            update_option( "category_$t_id", $cat_meta );
        }
    }
}
```

This should output the select 'Blog layout' when you add categories to your posts. Then in your `index.php` add

```
$cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
$cat_data = get_option("category_$cat_id");

<?php if(isset($cat_data['blog_layout']) && $cat_data['blog_layout'] == 'layout1'): ?>

\\Your layout1 here

<?php else: ?>

\\Your layout2 here

<?php endif; ?>
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue I replaces the entire single.php file with this code:

```
<?php
if (in_category('2')) {include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/page-case-study-post.php');
}
else { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/page-services-post.php');
}
?>;
```

sending either categories to two different pages depending on what its set to.