# WordPress unlimited sidebars

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, sidebar

Just wondering if someone could give me some advice on how to create unlimited sidebars for a WordPress theme.

So, basically I am looking into adding a meta box on posts and pages with a drop down list of all available sidebars, where the user can then select a specific sidebar for any post or page. This part I have figured out, however I would also like to add functionality here to allow users to create custom sidebars for any post or page. So, essentially the user could choose any sidebar for any post or page or create new sidebars for any post or page which then could be filled with widgets on the widgets page.

I half there, just not sure how to go about creating the functionality to create new sidebars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do it but it's a bit lengthy.

**Create a customizer control to add multiple sidebars**

The easiest way is to just take the custom control called *Multi Input field* from [here](https://github.com/dingo-d/wordpress-theme-customizer-extra-custom-controls). Also, be sure to add this custom control, and all the jQuery functionality that goes with it (in the .js file).

With that, add to your customizer file (or if you don't have a dedicated customizer file, to your `functions.php` file)

```
if(!function_exists('yourtheme_text_sanitization')){
    function yourtheme_text_sanitization($input){
        return wp_kses_post( force_balance_tags($input) );
    }
}


/**
------------------------------------------------------------
SECTION: Sidebars
------------------------------------------------------------
**/
$wp_customize->add_section('section_sidebars', array(
    'title'     => esc_html__('Sidebars', 'yourtheme'),
    'priority'  => 0,
));


    /**
    Sidebars
    **/
    $wp_customize->add_setting('sidebars', array(
        'default'     => '',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'yourtheme_text_sanitization',
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control(new Multi_Input_Custom_control($wp_customize, 'sidebars', array(
        'label'         => esc_html__( 'Sidebars', 'yourtheme' ),
        'description'   => esc_html__( 'Add as many custom sidebars as you need', 'yourtheme' ),
        'settings'      => 'sidebars',
        'section'       => 'section_sidebars',
    )));
```

The first function is the sanitization function for your customizer sanitization callback.

So now you should have 'Sidebars' in your Appearance > Customize menu.

**Create sidebars dynamically**

But now you need to add your sidebars. If you have a dedicated sidebar file like `sidebars.php` where you register your theme sidebars, you can put this there, or in your `functions.php` file

```
if ( function_exists( 'register_sidebar' ) ) {
    $sidebars=get_theme_mod('sidebars','');
    if($sidebars!=''){
        $sidebars = explode('|', $sidebars);
        $i = 0;
        foreach($sidebars as $sidebar){
            $i++;
            register_sidebar(array(
                'name'=>$sidebar,
                'id' => 'sidebar-'.$i,
                'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
                'after_widget' => '</div>',
                'before_title' => '<div class="sidebar-widget-heading"><h3>',
                'after_title' => '</h3></div>',
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the minimum you need so that you can add multiple sidebars in the theme, and they should appear in Appearance > Widgets.

**Add sidebar metabox**

Now adding a metabox to display them is relatively easy. In your `functions.php`, or a separate file where you add metaboxes to posts/pages/CPT, add

```
// Add metabox
add_action('admin_init', 'yourtheme_post_add_meta');
if ( ! function_exists( 'yourtheme_post_add_meta' ) ){
    function yourtheme_post_add_meta(){
        add_meta_box('post-sidebar', esc_html__('Select Sidebar', 'yourtheme'), 'yourtheme_post_sidebar_meta_box', 'post');
    }
}

//Metabox
if ( ! function_exists( 'yourtheme_post_sidebar_meta_box' ) ){
    function yourtheme_post_sidebar_meta_box( $post ){
        $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
        $custom_sidebar = (isset($values['custom_sidebar'][0])) ? $values['custom_sidebar'][0] : '';
        wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_sidebar_nonce', 'meta_box_sidebar_nonce' );
        ?>
        <p>
            <select name="custom_sidebar" id="custom_sidebar">
                <?php
                global $wp_registered_sidebars;
                $sidebar_replacements = $wp_registered_sidebars;
                if(is_array($sidebar_replacements) && !empty($sidebar_replacements)){
                    foreach($sidebar_replacements as $sidebar){
                        echo "<option value='{$sidebar['name']}'".selected($sidebar['name'], $custom_sidebar, false).">{$sidebar['name']}</option>";
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </p>
        <?php
    }
}

//Save Metabox
add_action( 'save_post', 'yourtheme_post_save_sidebar_meta_box' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'yourtheme_post_save_sidebar_meta_box' ) ){
    function yourtheme_post_save_sidebar_meta_box( $post_id ){
        if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ){
            return;
        }
        if( !isset( $_POST['custom_sidebar'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_sidebar_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_sidebar_nonce' ) ) {
            return;
        }
        if( !current_user_can( 'edit_pages' ) ) {
            return;
        }
        if( isset( $_POST['custom_sidebar'] ) ){
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'custom_sidebar', wp_kses( $_POST['custom_sidebar'] ,'') );
        }
    }
}
```

And this should be it. A bit lengthy, but a way to add as many sidebars to your theme as you wish :)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time for putting this together. I had been able to make the registered sidebars display on a drop down list on each post and page already. What I want to accomplish now is instead of having the functionality to add new sidebars in a settings page or as part of the customizer have a meta box which would allow users to create new sidebars on each post and page. I have trying to modify your code to implement this but haven't been successful yet.. Is this something you can help with?

Comment: Maybe by first creating a metabox with input field. From that input field you'd get the sidebar name you'd use as `$values = get_post_custom( $post->ID ); $sidebars = $values['sidebars'][0];`. Then in metabox save you'd have  `register_sidebar` function that uses the name you put in the input field to register sidebar. In the same metabox you'd have a sidebar dropdown. So that after you save the post, you'd get that name to choose from the dropdown. Seems kinda impractical tho :S

Comment: I just think that being able to add new sidebars on single posts and pages would be valuable, but maybe your approach makes more sense. Ok, I'll give it a try at fully implementing your approach. Just a couple more things, at the moment the footer sidebars are also showing on the registered sidebars drop down. How would I exclude them from the drop down? And also how would I after registering new sidebars apply them to different categories? Thank you very much

Comment: Excluding footer widgets? Prrobably by manually excluding them from the array `$sidebar_replacements`. First you'd fill a new array `$footer_array` where you'd put the names of the footer widgets and then use `array_diff()` to get new array that you'd pass to the foreach loop. If you want to apply sidebars to categories you'd need similar thing, but you'd use these hooks: `add_action ( 'edit_category_form_fields', 'mytheme_extra_category_fields'); add_action ( 'category_add_form_fields', 'mytheme_extra_add_category_fields');`

Comment: Oh and in addition to those hooks, you'd need: `add_action ( 'edited_category', 'mytheme_save_extra_category_fileds'); add_action ( 'created_category', 'mytheme_save_extra_category_fileds');` To save category fields. I made an answer here about adding stuff to category, I can't find it tho. I'll search it and paste it here.

Comment: Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33546585/open-wordpress-post-in-a-different-page/33547050#33547050

Basically it's the same thing as adding layout, but you put `<select name="Cat_meta[sidebar]">` and the foreach from the post with options. If you ask a new question I'll answer it there, since putting this in comments is clumsy at best...

Comment: Wow man, you definitely now your stuff.. When I grow up I wanna be just like you..lol Ok Ill create a new question when I get to work on the categories bit. Regarding the footer sidebars what I mean is at the moment I have a few sidebars registered in my functions.php file. a page sidebar,  a blog sidebar and four footer sidebars to display widgets in four footer sections. what I wanna do is hide the footer sidebars from the list of registered sidebars that shows in the meta box on each post and page.

Comment: As I said, excluding them should be done manually, so that when you output your `$sidebar_replacements` you don't get all the sidebars, but only the ones you want. Thanks for the compliment, I still have much to learn. Adding stuff in wordpress is not that hard, once you get to know how it works :) I have been working on wordpress themes for a year and a half now, and there are still some stuff that I don't understand :D

Comment: Isnt there another way of removing the footer sidebars from the drop down list of registered sidebars? array_diff() throws an error - array to sting conversion. I have tried other ways like array_slice but I don't think is the best way as users add new sidebars. The footer sidebars are the last 4 items in the $sidebar_replacements array, all I need is a way to remove these 4 last items, just not sure what's the most flexible way to do this considering that users will add new sidebars.

Comment: Well, since they are registered sidebars, I don't really think that there's another way of removing them :S

Comment: This is what I have: $footer_array = array( 'footer-sidebar-1' ); and then $updated_registered_sidebars = array_diff( $sidebar_replacements, $footer_array); and then I pass the new array $updated_registered_sidebars into the loop. So now it should show all the other sidebars with the exception of footer-sidebar-1 as it is the diference between them but its just not doing it. The code above is correct, isnt it? Thanks a lot buddy, Ill get out of your hair soon.. :D

Comment: Yep, that sounds about right :) If my answer was helpful, feel free to upvote it and accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Giving the users option to choose a sidebar is fine, but i dont think its a good idea to give them functionality to create their own sidebars. You will quickly get into the problem where you will have tons of sidebars in your widget area each for a different post.

However if i was in your situation, i would have created a single sidebar and then dynamically added widgets to this sidebar depending on the post that is being viewed. For the end user both will look the same. Anyways there is no right or wrong answer here, it depends on how you want to tackle the situation.

Comment: That is a very interesting approach. It would definitely be a much better way of making this functionality available. I guess you would have some sort of meta box displaying all  widgets available which could then be added to any page or post. I have bee searching for some examples which could help me implementing this but no luck so far. There are some plugins, but I would really like to avoid using plugins for this. Is there any resource you know of that could put me in the right path to accomplish this?

Comment: Well first of all you have to create a sidebar, and as you said you will have a meta box of all the widgets where users can add them to postmeta. Then in the code you will have to check for the widget id and add it to the sidebar. Here is an excellent resource to achieve this, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26557/programmatically-add-widgets-to-sidebars. Take your time for each block of code and read all the answers, and modify them according to your needs.

Comment: Will have a look. Thank you very much